# Add content dynamically on the basis of height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I am having a project on generating the pdf from html content. The PDF should contain the page header in each page. So, Is there any way to add the content dynamically after some height has been reached in the page? This is needed for setting the header in the top of A4 sized paper containing html contents that is to be rendered into pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can check actual display height and construct the content depending on it as the following example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 var dsheight = $(window).height();
    alert("page height: "+dsheight);
});
</script>
```

Or you can reach this checking the height of an html `<div>` (for example) and split it for X characters to reach this job.
Anyway it must be a better and simplest way to do it using some php (or the server side language that you want to use).
I created loads of pdf with php but I never taked too much care to headers, sincerely.